# Having a problem with my code where it should turn a user input value into a string but it doesn't

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

For my school assignment, they give us starter code that will will turn a number into a string and a string into a number. When I implemented my code it did not work and they told us to not change anything in the starter code.

```
#!/bin/bash

#######################################
# Check for quotes directory and setup menu options
if [ ! -d quotes ]
then
        echo "Error: quotes directory not found, make sure to unroll your tarball!" >&2
        exit 1
fi
cd quotes # Move into quotes directory
options=(* "Reprompt" "Exit") # Declare list
# TODO Set variable PS3 to desired prompt here
###################################
PS3="Pick a quote-sayer: "
echo "$PS3"
select var in "${options[@]}" # Syntax to loop over a list
do
        #######################################
        # Process input
        # Note: This section was written for you, no need to modify.
        # -var pulls in user-selection of the numeric menu options
        # -REPLY pulls in string user input
        # -i.e. 7) Exit
        #               -> var=7, REPLY="" if the user typed '7'
        #               -> var=, REPLY="Exit" if the user typed 'Exit'
        input=$var
        if [ -z "$var" ]
        then
                input=$REPLY
        fi
        #######################################

        # TODO: Respond to user-input. See assignment description for instructions
        # This is where most of your code will be written
        read input
        case $input in
        "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | "10" | "11")
        number=$input
        cd $number
        ls
        ;;
        "12")
        REPLY=
        ;;
        "13")
        break
        ;;
        esac
done
```

everything works and Im pretty sure it has something to do with my user input but don't know what it is

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think it is `I do not understand the assignment. What am I supposed to do?`. Did you try the script while having a `quotes` directory? Will you get a menu with different quotes to choose from? What part did you implement, what did you expect and what did you see?

Comment: *`it did not work`* doens't tell us anything useful ... did you get a (syntax) error? did the script hang? did the script generate the 'wrong' output? something else? how did you call the script, what were the input(s), what was the (wrong) output generated by your script and what is the (correct) expected output?

Comment: The "starter code" already populates the `input` variable with the file name. `read input` destroys what the user already gave you. You need to check if `$input` equals "Reprompt" or "Exit" or something else.

Comment: One error in the comments: if the user typed "7" the `var` variable will have the value "Exit"